# Mean position of a function defined by xyz points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an irregular 2D mesh and I have a list of the values of each cell, and its corresponding `x, y` coordinates (for the cell centre). I would like to find the mean position of the function.

In one dimension I do

```
x = numpy.array([0, 0.5, 1])
z = numpy.array([0, 1, 0])
scipy.integrate.simps(x * z, x)
```

but in two dimensions this isn't possible because `x` and `y` are not evenly spaced.

The function would return `(0, 0)` for this mesh:

[image]

that has these z values:

[image]

SOLUTION:

this is just a centre of mass problem so you can just do

```
x = 1/sum(masses) * sum(mass_at_x * x)
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete working example for the 1D case and example of data in the 2D case?

Comment: Please either delete this question or post your answer as an answer and not as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a centre of mass problem so you can just do

```
x = 1/sum(masses) * sum(mass_at_x * x)
```